# Regular Expression find method insight

Tags: java

This is my code for finding pattern "ab" in given string.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegExp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ab");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("ababbaba");
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.start());
        }
    }
}
```

In this code `while(m.find())` is not making sense for me. Because when first time `find()` will return `false` and  flow will come out of while loop. Then how can `find()` method can give all possible match in given string?

Comment: `find()` is some kind of "iterator".

Comment: `find()` will return true as long as there is a match and hence all the matches will be printed

Comment: [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) docs

Comment: Why do you ask a well answered question you already asked yourself again?

Comment: but when it returns false while will stop further so how can we get all match